# INTERVAL 30 DAY not giving expected result

Tags: php, mysql, date, intervals, between

I am somewhat familiar with the MySQL DATE and DATE_FORMAT.

However, when running a query for a date range, using INTERVAL - 30 DAY, am either not getting the correct output or it throws an error. Looking further into the table, realize that each row for date_buy is in this type of format: 
Mon 09 September 2015, etc. I have tried to use PHP date('D d F Y') instead of DATE(NOW()) and such, but am unable to resolve the issue. Is there another known workaround for this?

And yes, have tried a BETWEEN date_buy_x and date_buy_y. It returns nothing even though there are records in the table.

```
SELECT SUM(sales_total), date_buy FROM `Sebastian Estate Sales` 
WHERE date_buy >= $date - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
GROUP BY date_buy

SELECT SUM(sales_total), date_buy FROM `Sebastian Estate Sales` 
WHERE date_buy BETWEEN date_buy_x && date_buy_y
GROUP BY date_buy ORDER BY date_buy DESC
```

**UPDATE**

SO, based upon the suggestions, and looking further into the DATE_FORMAT and CURDATE parameters, have been able to display the data. The ORDER BY must also be in DATE_FORMAT(date_buy, '%a %d %M %Y') to output correctly. However, the issue still remains regarding INTERVAL 30 DAY parameter.

```
WHERE datebuy <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY,'%a %d %M %Y')
GROUP BY date_buy ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date_buy, '%a %d %M %Y') DESC
```

This is bringing back data but still way out of range, which makes me think it is not accepting the INTERVAL request.

```
Sat 22 November 2014 (50 sales) 
Thu 18 December 2014 (50 sales) 
Thu 22 January 2015 (20 sales) 
Sun 25 January 2015 (20 sales) 
Mon 06 April 2015 (25 sales) 
Sun 12 April 2015 (25 sales) 
Mon 03 August 2015 (10 sales)
```

When the output should only be:

```
Mon 03 August 2015 (10 sales)
```

Comment: don't store dates as strings! horror. fix the date storage, all else will fix its self

Comment: Dagon. The solution needs this particular date format for other displays across pages, which is why it stores in this manner. Fixing the current date in rows is going to be a pain.

Comment: Write something to read the dates out of that field, parse them, and save them in proper date format to a new field that you'll use from now on.

Comment: The need to display the date in that format in several pages means you use a select statement with `DATE_FORMAT(...)` to get it into that format, not that you store it in that format.

Comment: Correct. I inherited this from another Development Co. Am trying to find a perma-fix, versus a bandage. My first thought was to parse the current format, as suggested, removing the date(D) portion, then update all the records, but wanted to see if there was another, more relative solution.

Comment: you don't store data in the format you want to display it as, theses are different things.

Comment: Yes, I know this. Generally I prefer to use the DATE or TIMESTAMP instead. But, in this particular case the client needs the Day element. Am assuming this is why the string style was used.

Comment: VJK, yes I do. But, as said, need to retain the date(D) and store it for display.  Am curious though, why a string date cannot be read as a DATE or DATE_FORMAT.

Comment: Can you post the output of a `DESC \`Sebastian Estate Sales\``

Comment: this was a great resource: http://web.calstatela.edu/faculty/jchen13/Docs/CS122/Lectures/MysqlDateFormat.txt

Answer (score 0):

You could conceivably do:

```
SELECT SUM(sales_total), date_buy FROM `Sebastian Estate Sales` 
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_buy, '%a %d %M %Y')) >= $date - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
GROUP BY date_buy
```

Unless `$date` is also in this string format, in which case you need to use the STR_TO_DATE function on it too.

```
SELECT SUM(sales_total), date_buy FROM `Sebastian Estate Sales` 
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_buy, '%a %d %M %Y')) >= DATE(STR_TO_DATE($date, '%a %d %M %Y')) - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
GROUP BY date_buy
```

Comment: I completely overlooked the %a. I did try %W, which turned out to be the long-day. {{ face-plams self }}. Thanks mate. I'll give it a go.

Comment: hope you don't have a lot of data, as this is a performance killer

Comment: I'd use the STR_TO_DATE to parse the date and update a new field and then switch fields, or something like that, since constantly doing the conversion in where clauses will hurt performance

Answer (score 0):

how about `date_sub()`,use `date_format` to same format when query

```
SELECT SUM(sales_total), date_buy FROM `Sebastian Estate Sales` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date_buy,'%Y %m %d')) >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(DATE($date,INTERVAL 30 DAY),'%Y %m %d'))  
GROUP BY date_buy
```